# Hover on Button -> Opacity on other element

Tags: css

on my home page I have a grid block with 6 images on it

On hover, it becomes more transparent thanks to CSS (opacity: 0.6)

[image]

I also would like that when I hover on the button at the center of the image, the image itself keeps being transparent

Since it's not the case here

[image]

So I have applied some code here, but I couldn't figure why it doesn't work

```
.flexItem.grid_sections .button:hover ~ .grid_sections img {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Those elements appear on my homepage, 5th section
URL: https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/

Any idea?
Let me know, and thank you in advance :)
Pascal

Comment: is possible  jquery? jquery good for you?

Comment: There's no way to select elements up the DOM with CSS, you'll have to either use JS or rearrange your HTML.

Comment: oh ok :/
Unfortunately I can't control that since I use with a theme

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't/how to make this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Hello LGSon, I am a bit surprised on this comment. I find I was particularly clear on the send, the desired behavior and the error. I have also written the shortest code necessary to my solution, to get it fixed. And I have let the community aware that I was using a theme, so I cannot play on the HTML environment, but just on the settings of my theme. Which is why I don't get the downvote

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```css
div {
  height: 260px;
  width: 260px;
  position: relative;
}

div > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

div > button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 45%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 45px;
}

div > button:hover + img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Button</button>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x260">
</div>
```

NOTE: you must put the `button` tag before `img` tag

Comment: Hello guys, though your solution didn't work, I'd like to thank you for the time spent, I have asked my theme developer to get this into account for a future update

Comment: mmmh ok I couldn't adapt the code, but I'll try deeper, thanks for notifying :)